# NFS mounts failing if FIREHOL firewall started

Tags: linux, firewall, nfs

I am trying to setup NFS mounts between two machines on the same local network, however it seems I need to be more specific in my firewall (FIREHOL) setup as the client side cannot mount the exports.

Did look at netstat to determine the ports that open up, but they seems to be non-static/changing.

I know it is firewall related as disabled/stopping my Firehol causes the problem to dissapear.

Any specific areas I should investigate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, you need to make sure that portmap is also enabled in your Firehol configuration. 
I am not super sure about the low level workings of NFS's ports, but it does not use the same ports everytime.
You could do something like the following to enable the NFS ports, as well as portmap. (Check rpcinfo -p)
This would enable the rpc queries (to determine the ports, for the firewall, to know AFTER NFS was started(or restarted))
I also suggest the use of 'src' to restrict the client IP's you are serving to, if you don't already have it :)

Lastly, remember to restart the firewall/firehol AFTER nfs restarts, so rpcqueries are happy with the ports for nfs service.

Example (where 192.168.152.176 is your client machine)
        server  portmap accept  src     192.168.152.176
        server  nfs     accept  src     192.168.152.176

Comment: This has done it, I really did not know NFS was one of these. I moved the start procedure scripts in rc2.d to make sure firehol is started after nfs too. Thanks kind sir.